# How to monitor admin access in Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a cra + firestore app and I have implemented security rules.

Let's say someone figures out the uid of another user and changes that in the url. My security rule will prevent the user from reading that document. I would like to log this information either using google analytics or just purely saving it in a separate collection.
I would like to identify who is trying to "hack" the application. Could you give me some suggestion/guidance how I should go about monitoring that behavior?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no logging of security rule violations.  I suggest filing a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  You can try to log a permission failure in the app, but that's not guaranteed to happen since client code can be bypassed.

Comment: Hi Doug, I just filed a feature request. Thank you for bringing that up. I wonder if there is any specific error-code that I can check on the client side when a security rule has been violated? Thanks

Comment: You will see an error with "permission denied" in the message. This should be an easy situation to simulate.